# Ionic 4 --background transition

Tags: background, ionic4, transition, background-color

how to make transition of background-color of ion-toolbar?

The problem is, in Ionic 4 the background-color is set by --background.

This is my NOT working .scss code:

```
ion-toolbar.transparent{
    --background: red;
    transition: 1000ms linear;
}

ion-toolbar.transparent:hover{
    --background: green;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please check the below codes, remove the transparent class name from the ion-toolbar, also don't use color attribute in ion-toolbar

```
<ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
        Ionic Title
    </ion-title>
</ion-toolbar>
```

For style

```
ion-toolbar{
    --background: red;
    transition: 1000ms linear;
}

ion-toolbar:hover{
    --background: green;
}
```

Comment: Your code works the same as mine. My ion-toolbar changes the color after hover but the transition is no working.